# P/Invoke bug or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, pinvoke, win32-process

So, I wrote the following code:

```
using (var serviceController = new ServiceController(serviceName))
{
    var serviceHandle = serviceController.ServiceHandle;

    using (failureActionsStructure.Lock())
    {
        success = NativeMethods.ChangeServiceConfig2W(
            serviceHandle,
            ServiceConfigType.SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS,
            ref failureActionsStructure);

        if (!success)
            throw new Win32Exception();
    }
}
```

The P/Invoke declaration is as follows:

```
[DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool ChangeServiceConfig2W(IntPtr hService, ServiceConfigType dwInfoLevel, ref SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONSW lpInfo);
```

`ServiceConfigType` is just an `enum`, and this particular member has value 2. The `SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONSW` structure is defined as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
struct SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONSW
{
    public int dwResetPeriod;
    public string lpRebootMsg;
    public string lpCommand;
    public int cActions;
    public IntPtr lpsaActionsPtr;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    public SC_ACTION[] lpsaActions;

    class DataLock : IDisposable
    {
        IntPtr _buffer;

        public DataLock(ref SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONSW data)
        {
            int actionStructureSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SC_ACTION));

            // Allocate a buffer with a bit of extra space at the end, so that if the first byte isn't aligned to a 64-bit
            // boundary, we can simply ignore the first few bytes and find the next 64-bit boundary.
            _buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.lpsaActions.Length * actionStructureSize + 8);

            data.lpsaActionsPtr = _buffer;

            // Round up to the next multiple of 8 to get a 64-bit-aligned pointer.
            if ((data.lpsaActionsPtr.ToInt64() & 7) != 0)
            {
                data.lpsaActionsPtr += 8;
                data.lpsaActionsPtr -= (int)((long)data.lpsaActionsPtr & ~7);
            }

            // Copy the data from lpsaActions into the buffer.
            IntPtr elementPtr = data.lpsaActionsPtr;

            for (int i=0; i < data.lpsaActions.Length; i++, elementPtr += actionStructureSize)
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(data.lpsaActions[i], elementPtr, fDeleteOld: false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_buffer);
        }
    }

    internal IDisposable Lock()
    {
        return new DataLock(ref this);
    }
}
```

(This type has an extra member at the end of the structure that doesn't appear in the native structure definition, `lpsaActions`, which simplifies the use of this struct and results only in extra data being marshalled in at the end -- data that the underlying API simply ignores because it assumes the struct has already come to an end in memory.)

`SC_ACTION` is defined like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SC_ACTION
{
    public SC_ACTION_TYPE Type;
    public int Delay;
}
```

..and `SC_ACTION_TYPE` is a straightforward `enum`:

```
enum SC_ACTION_TYPE
{
    SC_ACTION_NONE = 0,
    SC_ACTION_RESTART = 1,
    SC_ACTION_REBOOT = 2,
    SC_ACTION_RUN_COMMAND = 3,
}
```

The structure I'm passing in is initialized like this:

```
var failureActionsStructure =
    new SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONSW()
    {
        dwResetPeriod = 60000, // 60 seconds
        lpRebootMsg = "",
        lpCommand = "",
        cActions = 6,
        lpsaActions =
            new SC_ACTION[]
            {
                new SC_ACTION() { Type = SC_ACTION_TYPE.SC_ACTION_RESTART /* 1 */, Delay = 5000 /* 5 seconds */ },
                new SC_ACTION() { Type = SC_ACTION_TYPE.SC_ACTION_RESTART /* 1 */, Delay = 15000 /* 15 seconds */ },
                new SC_ACTION() { Type = SC_ACTION_TYPE.SC_ACTION_RESTART /* 1 */, Delay = 25000 /* 25 seconds */ },
                new SC_ACTION() { Type = SC_ACTION_TYPE.SC_ACTION_RESTART /* 1 */, Delay = 35000 /* 35 seconds */ },
                new SC_ACTION() { Type = SC_ACTION_TYPE.SC_ACTION_RESTART /* 1 */, Delay = 45000 /* 45 seconds */ },
                new SC_ACTION() { Type = SC_ACTION_TYPE.SC_ACTION_NONE /* 0 */, Delay = 0 /* immediate, and this last entry is then repeated indefinitely */ },
            },
    };
```

When I run this code within a 64-bit process, it works just fine. When I run it in a 32-bit process, though (actually I have only tested 32-bit processes on 32-bit Windows installations -- I don't know for certain what happens in a 32-bit process on a 64-bit Windows installation), I always get `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` back.

I did a bit of digging. The `ChangeServiceConfig2W` API function uses the `stdcall` calling convention, which means that when the first opcode in the function is about to execute, the stack should consist of:

- (DWORD PTR) Return Address
- (DWORD PTR) Service Handle
- (DWORD) Service Config Type (2)
- (DWORD PTR) Pointer to Failure Actions Structure

However, when I attach a native debugger to my 32-bit C# process and put a breakpoint on the first instruction of `ChangeServiceConfig2W` (technically the first instruction of `_ChangeServiceConfig2WStub@12`), I find that the stack consists of:

- (DWORD PTR) Return Address
- (DWORD PTR) Always the value 0x0000AFC8
- (DWORD) The value 0x00000001, not 2 as expected
- (DWORD PTR) Actually a valid pointer to the Failure Actions Structure

I confirmed with a simple C++ application that the second and third `DWORD`s off of `[ESP]` *should* be the Service Handle and constant value 2. I tried various alternative P/Invoke declarations, including using `int` instead of `IntPtr` and `ServiceConfigType` for the first two arguments, but could not get any other behaviour.

Finally, I changed the third parameter, the `ref SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONSW`, to take `IntPtr` directly instead, and manually marshalled the `failureActionsStruct` using `Marshal.StructureToPtr` into a block allocated with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`. With this declaration, the first and second arguments now marshal correctly.

So, my question is, am I doing something wrong in the way that I initially declared the `ChangeServiceConfig2W` function, something that could account for the first two arguments not marshalling correctly? The likelihood seems small, but I can't shake the possibility that I'm running into an actual bug in P/Invoke (specifically the marshaler) here.

Curiously, the `DWORD` value `0x0000AFC8` is the 45,000 ms `Delay` from one of the `SC_ACTION` structures within `failureActionsStructure` I am passing in. However, it is the last member of that instance, and the `0x00000001` that follows `0x0000AFC8` in the stack would not be the `Type` of the following `SC_ACTION`. Even if it were, I cannot see what would cause those values to be written specifically to the parameters area for the P/Invoke call. If it were serializing the entire structure to the wrong place in memory and overwriting part of the stack, wouldn't that cause memory corruption and probably terminate the process?

I am confused. :-)

Comment: I wonder what happens if you add explicit `Marshal` attributes on other fields and/or `[In]/[Out]` on `lpInfo`.

Comment: I didn't try all possible combinations, but I experimented a bit with that and it didn't have any effect. I tried `UnmanagedType.I4`, since knowing this is a 32-bit process, a pointer converts transparently to/from a 32-bit `int`. The `2` value passed into the second argument is, of course, already effectively an `int`. This configuration still passed in "45000" as the `hService` pointer and "1" for the `ServiceConfigType` value that should have been 2.

Comment: I didn't try it, code looks good, but it fits the pattern.  Microsoft had a big job to do to allow 32-bit processes that run in wow64 to manipulate system components that are fundamentally 64-bit.  Notoriously plug & play is quite incomplete.  And I wouldn't be surprised at all if this wasn't done either.  Only the Services applet ever uses this api, it is 64-bit.  Just remove the jitter forcing on your EXE project so it can run in the native bitness of the OS.  Project > Properties > Build tab.

Comment: You misunderstand -- it *is* set to target "Any CPU" without "Prefer 32-bit", but it is not working correctly as a 32-bit process *on a 32-bit OS*. It works fine as a 64-bit process on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Hmm, good luck getting somebody to repro this then :) Do fix your snippet please, you cannot convert ServiceHandle (a SafeHandle) to IntPtr.

Comment: On Windows 7 x64, having selected x86 in the project properties and having created a dummy native x86 library that exports `ChangeServiceConfig2W` with identical signature, I get `System.ExecutionEngineException` when the `SizeConst` is 1, 2 or 3. When it's 4, 5 or 6 the call seemingly succeeds. When it's more than 6, it's an `ArgumentException` about array packing.

Comment: `System.ExecutionEngineException` happens after the native call returns, `ArgumentException` happens before the call. In all cases where the call reaches the dll, it seems to receive correct values in the three arguments.

Comment: Create your own dll with a function having the appropriate signature. Call it from your c# code. Inspect what arrives in that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have figured out what is going on. In my opinion, it *is* a bug in the P/Invoke marshaler, but I wouldn't be surprised if Microsoft's official line were, "This behaviour is by design."

When you configure an array to be marshaled within a struct, your options are very constrained. From what I can tell, you can use `UnmanagedType.SafeArray` for any of the `VARIANT` primitive types, or you can use `UnmanagedType.ByValArray`, which requires you to specify `SizeConst` -- that is, the marshaler supports only embedded arrays that are always exactly the same length.

The `Marshal.SizeOf` function, then, when computing the size of the structure, counts the size of the array as `SizeConst * Marshal.SizeOf(arrayElementType)`. This is always the case, regardless of the actual size of the array an instance points to.

The bug appears to be that the marshaler always copies all elements in the array, even if that number is greater than `SizeConst`. So, as in my situation, if you set `SizeConst` to 1, but supply an array with 6 elements, then it allocates memory based on `Marshal.SizeOf`, which allocates a single slot for array data, and then proceeds to marshal all 6 elements, writing past the end of the buffer and corrupting memory.

The reason the stack slots for parameters were corrupted in this manner can be explained only by the marshaler allocating memory for this serialization on the stack. By overflowing the end of that buffer, it then overwrote data further up the stack, including the spot where, ultimately, the return address gets written and the first two arguments that had already been placed into their slots on the stack. After this marshaling operation, it then wrote a pointer to that stack buffer into the third argument, explaining why the third argument's value was, in fact, a valid pointer to the data structure.

I was lucky, with my particular configuration, that the end of the 6th element occurred before corrupting other elements further up the stack, in that only the first two arguments to `ChangeServiceConfig2W` were being damaged -- code was able to continue to execute after `ChangeServiceConfig2W` returned its error about the handle being invalid. With a larger array, or a simpler function where the buffer allocated by the marshaler was closer to the end of the stack frame, it could very well have overwritten important data further up the stack and resulted in an `ExecutionEngineException` as @GSerg saw.

On 64-bit systems, there must be more free space on the stack -- for one thing, all pointers are now 64 bits wide, so that spaces things out. Writing past the end of the buffer, then, isn't getting as far up the stack and isn't managing to corrupt the first or second argument to `ChangeServiceConfig2W`. This is how this code worked in initial testing and appeared to be correct.

In my opinion, this is a bug in the marshaler; it has enough information to avoid corrupting memory (just don't marshal more than `SizeConst` elements, because that's all the memory you have allocated!), but it goes ahead and writes past the end of the allocated buffer anyway. I can see the converse philosophy, which is, "If you've told the marshaler `SizeConst` is 1, then don't supply an array with more than 1 element." But there is no clear warning that doing so can corrupt the execution environment in any of the documentation that I read. Given the lengths that .NET goes to to avoid that type of corruption, I have to think of this as a bug in the marshaler.

I have gotten my code working by updating the `DataLock` class, which temporarily prepares the `lpsaActions` data as a pointer-to-array (which `ChangeServiceConfig2W` requires and the default P/Invoke marshaler does not appear to support), to stash the real `lpsaActions` array and replace it with a dummy 1-element array. This prevents the marshaler from then marshaling more than 1 element, and the memory corruption does not occur. When the `DataLock` object is `Dispose`d, it restores `lpsaActions` to its previous value.

I have placed this (working) code into a public GitHub repo, along with an essentially identical C++ version that I used to compare the state of registers and the stack as code flow entered the `ChangeServiceConfig2W` function during my diagnosis:

- https://github.com/logiclrd/TestServiceFailureActionChange

To reproduce the problem I was seeing, comment out these lines from `WindowsAPI/SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONSW.cs`:

```
            // Replace the lpsaActions array with a dummy that contains only one element, otherwise the P/Invoke marshaller
            // will allocate a buffer of size 1 and then write lpsaActions.Length items to it and corrupt memory.
            _originalActionsArray = data.lpsaActions;

            data.lpsaActions = new SC_ACTION[1];
```

Then, run the program as a 32-bit process. (If you are on a 64-bit operating system, which is likely, you'll need to adjust the build configuration so that it either specifies "Prefer 32-bit" or targets the "x86" platform directly.)

Microsoft may or may not become aware of and fix this bug. At the very least, it would be good of Microsoft to update the documentation for `UnmanagedType.ByValArray` to include a warning about this possible scenario -- I'm not sure how to convey that to them. Given that current releases of .NET have it, though, I think it is best to simply avoid supplying arrays whose length is not exactly equal to `SizeConst` when marshaling structures to unmanaged code. :-)

Comment: But you used IntPtr so this theory cannot apply.  Nor could it produce an ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE error return.  You didn't fix the bug with the way you treat SafeHandle, what's up with that?

Comment: In the course of diagnosis, when I was scratching my head trying to figure out what was wrong, I changed the P/Invoke declaration from using `SafeHandle` to `IntPtr`, and then later to `int`. This had no effect on the outcome; it was returning `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` either way, and the reason was that the stack space for that argument was being overwritten. It didn't matter what was actually used for that argument; at the time of the call it was a few bytes from the middle of the `SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONSW` struct in that slot. I'll switch the code in the repo back to `SafeHandle`, for you. :-)

Comment: This is done now. You should find that the code, as now committed, works on 32-bit systems (and probably on 64-bit systems once more, now that it's been switched back from `int` to a proper pointer type), and that it yields `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` if you comment out the code in `SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONSW.cs` that replaces `lpsaActions` with a dummy 1-element array.